# TSQL Finding Overlapping Hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When two tables are given

**Employee Table**

```
EmpID  Name
1      Jon   
2      Smith  
3      Dana 
4      Nancy
```

**Lab Table**

```
EmpID   StartTime   EndTime    Date            LabID
1       10:00 AM    12:15 PM   01/JAN/2000     Lab I 
1       11:00 AM    14:15 PM   01/JAN/2000     Lab II 
1       16:30 PM    18:30 PM   01/JAN/2000     Lab I

2      10:00 AM    12:10 PM    01/JAN/2000     Lab I
```

From the given details ,I have to find out the overlapping hours,and non overlapping hours of each employee on each date. (**StartTime and EndTime are of type varchar**).

```
The expected output is 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EmpID| Name|  Overlapping                 | Non-Overlapping      |    Date 
              Period                        Period  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Jon | 10:00 AM  to 12:15 PM       |16:30 PM to   18:30 PM | 01/JAN/2000   
           |  AND                        |                       | 
           |  11:00 AM  to 14:15 PM      |                       |
           |  AND ...(If any)            |                       | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2    Smith|      NULL                    | 10:00 AM to 12:10 PM  |01/JAN/2000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me to bring such output using TSQL(SQL Server 2005/2008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should probably consider using a DateTime field to store the StartTime and EndTime, and thus make calculations easier, and remove the need for the Date field.

```
SELECT t1.EmpID, 
       t1.StartTime, 
       t1.EndTime,
       t2.StartTime
       t2.EndTime,
FROM lab t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN lab t2
   ON t2.StartTime BETWEEN t1.StartTime AND t1.EndTime
      AND t2.EmpID = t1.EmpID
ORDER BY t1.EmpID,
         t1.StartTime,
         t2.StartTime
```

That won't get you the EXACT format you have listed, but it's close. You should end up with:

```
| EmpID|   Name|    Normal Period    | Overlapping Period  |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1    |   Jon | 10:00 AM | 12:15 PM | 11:00 AM | 02:15 PM |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 2    | Smith | 10:00 AM | 12:10 PM | NULL     | NULL     |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Each overlapped period within a normal period would show up in a new row, but any period with no overlaps would have only one row. You could easily concatenate the fields if you wanted specifically the "xx:xx xx to xx:xx xx" format. Hope this helps you some.